# Array of an even number of integers and pair

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, integer

I want to make an array of an even number of integers to be given given as pairs in the order 
               and to be like this:

height_1, IQ_1, height_2, IQ_2, etc.

The input will be like this:

```
1651    13000     
1735    13300     
1700    12850     
1630    13500     
1991    13770
```

Please Help!

Comment: later on the  method will return the length of a longest sequence of
 people such that the heights are strictly increasing, but the IQs are strictly decreasing using "Longest Increasing Subsequence"

I know its difficult but if you say to me the first part I will be happy, please help me :s

Comment: @KshitijMehta The other question is the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described in your duplicate question:

> but the thing is that you can put as may pairs as you can

Then you should use a `List` (like `ArrayList` for instance) rather than an array. You'll then be able to add an arbitrary number of elements.

Also, you should make a pre-defined class to hold the height and the IQ. Let's call it `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    public final int height;
    public final int iq;

    public Person(int height, int iq) {
        this.height = height;
        this.iq = iq;
    }
}
```

That'll make it easier to group the heights and IQ's together.